# Regex to get just image name PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, match

Hello guys I want to get the image name from one line in html. I am doing in PHP  for example I have this lines

```
<img src="index_files/bottle2.jpg" name="product ds Grodsdwth" class="pullleft">

<img title="" src="index_files/ss-button.png" class="step-btn" alt=""></a>
```

I want jus get the **bottle2.jpg and ss-button.png** and replace it with **{#CDNPath#}img/imageName** to get This Result

```
 <img title="" src="{#CDNPath#}img/ss-button.png" class="step-btn" alt=""></a>
```

I have this regex but it doesn't work:

```
([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
```

I am confused with this escaped and patters please I will thankful with you guys

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/oA0rV6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this RegEx:

```
(<img.*?src=")((?:\w+\/)+?)([\w-]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))"
```

- The **`1st` Capture Group** stores the opening `<img` and other attributes, then the `src="`
- The **`2nd` Capture Group** stores the image folder(s), i.e. `index_files/` or `index_files/a/`
- The **`3rd` Capture Group** stores the image name

Replace with:

```
$1{#CDNPath#}img/$3"
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oN4hO4/2)</kbd>

Comment: Aweasome just a doubt at the end of tag src its missing one " isnt ?

Comment: @MarcoPerez Yes, just a add a `"` to the end of the replace (or use a positive lookahead - replace the last `"` in the RegEx with `(?=")`, and keep your replace the same). I have updated answer

Comment: Yes men Sure !! Thanks a lot Its difficult for me Regex I am lokking for a tutorial some expressions are so hard for me

Comment: @MarcoPerez Just do a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorials). The first few links are all very good sites to learn RegEx. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)